# Can I change the settings for the Save as PDF function in Word 2010?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2010

When I save a Word document as PDF, the PDF file seems to get a standard "initial view" setting. Is it possible to change that so that created PDF files open with Magnification=Fit Page?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to control the Initial View settings for the PDF being generated when exporting a PDF from Word using the built-in Save As PDF feature.

These settings can't be modified in Adobe Reader unfortunately so you will need to find a PDF editor that lets you change the settings. There's a few free options, one of them is [Debenu PDF Tools](http://www.debenu.com/products/desktop/debenu-pdf-tools/), a free utility for manipulating PDF files (that is provided by the company I work for).